# Sorting custom class array-list string using Collections.sort

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, arraylist

I am trying to sort my custom class array-list using Collections.sort  by declaring my own anonymous comparator. But the sort is not working as expected.

My code is

```
Collections.sort(arrlstContacts, new Comparator<Contacts>() {

        public int compare(Contacts lhs, Contacts rhs) {

            int result = lhs.Name.compareTo(rhs.Name);

            if(result > 0)
            {
                return 1;

            }
            else if (result < 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
```

The result is not in sorted order.

Comment: You know you can just use "return lhs.Name.compareTo(rhs.Name)" ?

Comment: Under which conditions is this not working?  Try stepping through with the debugger and/or writing some unit tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like Adam says, simply do:

```
Collections.sort(
  arrlstContacts, 
  new Comparator<Contacts>() 
  {
    public int compare(Contacts lhs, Contacts rhs) 
    {
      return lhs.Name.compareTo(rhs.Name);
    }
  }
);
```

The method [`String.compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) performs a lexicographical comparison which your original code is negating.  For example the strings `number1` and `number123` when compared would produce -2 and 2 respectively.

By simply returning 1, 0 or -1 there's a chance (as is happening for you) that the merge part of the merge sort used `Collections.sort` method is unable to differentiate sufficiently between the strings in the list resulting in a list that isn't alphabetically sorted.

Answer (score 7):

As indicated by Adam, you can use `return (lhs.Name.compareTo(rhs.Name));` likeso:

```
Collections.sort(arrlstContacts, new Comparator<Contacts>() {
     public int compare(Contacts lhs, Contacts rhs) {
         return (lhs.Name.compareTo(rhs.Name));
     }
});
```

Comment: Might want to cite [Adam's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091110/sorting-custom-class-array-list-string-using-collections-sort#comment12923708_10091110).

Comment: Didn't see that it has been answered already in the comments. Editing... Thanks!